# IntelliJ Web Module Dependencies on other Module

Tags: java, jsp, web, intellij-idea

I created a new web module in IntelliJ. The java classes in my src folder make calls to classes in another module, which is causing some java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError errors at runtime (everything is compiling correctly though). Is there a way to add a dependency such that the jsp files in my web app are properly able to access these java classes in this separate module?

Here's the error:

```
Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

"Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:129)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:60)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs."
```

Comment: Make sure the module is added to the dependencies of the web app module per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-module-dependencies.html and the jars from that module are also deployed with your artifact: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.